# groupBy Id and get multiple records for multiple columns in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe as below.

```scala
val df = Seq(("a",1,1400),("a",1,1250),("a",2,1200),("a",4,1250),("a",4,1200),("a",4,1100),("b",2,2500),("b",2,1250),("b",2,500),("b",4,250),("b",4,200),("b",4,100),("b",4,100),("b",5,800)).
toDF("id","hierarchy","amount")
```

I am working in scala language to make use of this data frame and trying to get result as shown below.

```scala
val df = Seq(("a",1,1400),("a",4,1250),("a",4,1200),("a",4,1100),("b",2,2500),("b",2,1250),("b",4,250),("b",4,200),("b",4,100),("b",5,800)).
toDF("id","hierarchy","amount")
```

Rules: Grouped by id, if min(hierarchy)==1 then I take the row with the highest **amount** and then I go on to analyze **hierarchy >= 4** and take 3 of each of them in descending order of the **amount**. On the other hand, if min(hierarchy)==2 then I take two rows with the highest **amount** and then I go on to analyze **hierarchy >= 4** and take 3 of each of them in descending order of the **amount**. And so on for all the id's in the data.

Thanks for the suggestions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use window functions to generate the criteria which you will filter upon eg

```
val results = df.withColumn("minh",min("hierarchy").over(Window.partitionBy("id")))
                .withColumn("rnk",rank().over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("amount").desc())))
                .withColumn(
                    "rn4",
                    when(col("hierarchy")>=4, row_number().over(
                     Window.partitionBy("id",when(col("hierarchy")>=4,1).otherwise(0)).orderBy(col("amount").desc())
                     ) ).otherwise(5)
                )
                .filter("rnk <= minh or rn4 <=3")
                .select("id","hierarchy","amount")
```

*NB. More verbose filter `.filter("(rnk <= minh or rn4 <=3) and (minh in (1,2))")`*

Above temporary columns generated by window functions to assist in the filtering criteria are

- `minh` : used to determine the minimum hierarchy for a group id and subsequently select the top minh number of columns from the group .
- `rnk` used to determine the rows with the highest amount in each group
- `rn4` used to determine the rows with the highest amount in each group with hierarchy >=4

Comment: [db fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eZGuVtKj4bKbtuUPUmRXiu/1)